# Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 keeps logging me out of websites

Tags: windows-explorer

Cookies are enabled, reset all settings several times, deleted Norton Internet Security, tried the Regedit fix (cache-old).  Nothing works.  Chrome keeps me logged in, but I need to use Internet Explorer and it's frustrating how it keeps logging me out of all websites every time I exit.  It remembers passwords though, but I have to relog-in.  I have tried disabling and enabling it in Windows 10, but there is no way you can delete it or downgrade to IE10.  Any ideas?

Comment: It is not possible to downgrade to Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: When you did the IE Reset, did you select the lower half (check the box) as this deletes forms and passwords. Do that, restart and test.

Answer (score 0):

yes I have been doing that, just tried resetting the whole thing again and now I cannot even log in to my google account from the main google page, it refreshes and has the "sign in" icon again and again; I have to go into youtube or gmail to be able to log in to google.   this is ridiculous, happened out of nowhere.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Super User! It seems like you may have accidentally created a new account. Unfortunately, this can hinder the ability to answer questions effectively (since you can't comment on/update your original posts, etc.). Please have a look at this [Super User Help Center article](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) if you need to potentially merge them.